# How could I create a select box which changes the contents of a div in Drupal 6?

Tags: drupal, select, html, drop-down-menu

Our client would like a page which has a select drop down and based on the item selected on this drop down would populate data to a div on that page. So for example, the list might include:

Orange
Banana
Apple

If the user selects Apple it loads some information about Apple's in a div on this page.

Doing this with jQuery, with `$(whatever).html('some content');` would be pretty simple enough. Even using `$.post()` to ajax the data, but im not sure how this would work inside a Drupal node.

Im pretty confident with Drupal but not really in customising it like this.